# CSS how to make a website scalable for 1600x1200

Tags: css, layout, web

Im trying to make some sort of liquid-fixed weblayout with CSS. The problem is that the site isn't very big, so when users with big screen resolution visits the site it looks very small and empty.So I need the menubar(which is located in the bottom) and some of the main elements to use some more screen space, when visited with larger screen resolutions. Sort of "scale to fit" can anybody help me out please?

My CSS styling as for now is just made as a fixed weblayout.

Comment: I need to adjust the whitespace between the elements on the website, depending on screen resolution. It's only images I need to adjust.

Answer (score 1):

Read this: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

and try to avoid using PX for widths, use % more :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, very quick answer :) I'll try this

Comment: I don't think it was what I needed although it was a very helpful article :) we nearly don't have any text on our website, so it's a lot of images. I need to adjust the whitespace between those elements, depending on screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this useful too, if you are looking for a cross-browser method for responsive web designs. It's called Respond.js:

https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

There are also some good snippets and theory in this article from Smashing Magazine:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/

Here is some more information from WebDesignerDepot:

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2011/09/the-ultimate-responsive-web-design-roundup/

EDIT: Updated with a nice new anything and everything roundup from WebDesignerDepot

Comment: Updated with a new link.
Hope it's useful.